# Further simplify, if possible, an expression containing two Hypergeometric2F1 functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions, algebraic-manipulation

I've encountered the expression

```
((1 - R14^2 u^2)^((1 + a)/2)
Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-1 - a), (1 + a)/2, (3 + a)/2, 
R14^2] - (1 - R14^2)^((1 + a)/2)
Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-1 - a), (1 + a)/2, (3 + a)/2, R14^2 u^2]),
```

where $R14 \in [0,1]$, $u \in [0,1]$ and $a \geq 0$.

Is this expression (further) simplifiable? I would hope--foolheartedly perhaps--to be able to integrate it over $R14 \in [0,1]$. Note, of course, that the two hypergeometric functions are identical, but for the (closely related) last of their four arguments.

With the transformation $a \rightarrow d-1$, and a certain normalization (relevant to my particular problem, but seemingly not necessary to detail here) and some successful integrations, I've reduced my remaining question to the integration over $R14 \in [0,1]$ of

```
-4 R14^(-1 + d) (R14 u)^d (1 - R14^2 u^2)^(d/2) Gamma[d]
Hypergeometric2F1[-(d/2), d/2, (2 + d)/2, R14^2]
```

I've tried the three Pfaff transformations that J. M. brought to attention, but these do not seem successful in this context. So, perhaps this is as far as I can get here. (Maybe an integration-by-parts strategy might work on this last expression--I'll give it a try.)

Regarding the comment of MarcoB, I was hoping to keep $d=a+1$ as a free parameter.

Comment: Does numerical integration with an appropriate `a` value work? If so, could you use integrate numerically when you need the value of the expression? More in general, I assume that you have already tried `Simplify` etc, so isn't this more a math question than a *Mathematica* one?

Comment: I won't argue your point, MarcoB. Looking now a little more closely at the underlying definition of Hypergeometric2F1, and doing some (combined) expansions, I don't think that I can make meaningful further progress here. I was initially being somewhat naive, I think--hoping too quickly for some sophisticated Mathematica wizardry.

Comment: Using the [Pfaff transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1) on your expression, I get `(1 - R14^2)^((1 + a)/2)*(1 - R14^2*u^2)^((1 + a)/2)*(-((-1 + R14^2)*Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 + a, (3 + a)/2, R14^2]) + (-1 + R14^2*u^2)*Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 + a, (3 + a)/2, R14^2*u^2])`.

Comment: J.M.--Is there a Jacobian associated with this Pfaff transformation? After using Expand on the transformed result, and trying to integrate over $R14 \in [0,1]$ on the four resultant parts, I seem to get divergent integrals, while I don't get this if I proceed similarly on the original/untransformed form. Did you use a specific one of the three Pfaff transformations listed in your link? I can integrate two of the three subparts of the original expression over $R14 \in [0,1]$, but not the remaining third subpart.